# Subnet and host in network subject

Tags: networking

I have a question:

Into how many subnets can we separate the network id 10.1.0.0/14 if the maximum number of hosts in each subnet is 18?

I found it as 64 subnets but I'm not sure about that because the part of maximum confuses me a little bit.

Please can you help me?

Comment: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A

Answer (score 0):

There are 32 bits in an IPv4 address and since 14 are fixed in that network id that means 18 are left floating.  That leaves 2 to the 18th power addresses free which is 262144.  Since each subnet has at most 18 hosts and you need one more for broadcast that means you need up to 19 addresses per subnet.  Since we can only make subnets with even powers of 2 you will need to use 32 addresses for each subnet (/5 subnets). So the answer is 262144/32 = 8192 subnets.